# Java. Вывод информации в файл

Tags: java

Есть написанный код, который ищет в определенной папке файлы по маске и, есои находит, выводит список этих файлов. Вывод стандартный в консоли. Хотелось бы сделать работу программы удобнее:
1. Создать графическое окошко с одной кнопкой, по нажатию которой выводило бы этот список файлов в специальное поле в этом же окошке. Как это сделать?
2. Вывести список файлов в файл *.txt. Как это реализовать?

То есть все то, что выводится в консоли в результате выполнения кода - как это все переместить в графическое окошко либо в txt-файл?

Comment: можно просто стандартный вывод в файл перенаправить: `команда_запуска_вашей_программы всякие параметры > file.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для первого я бы порекомендовал JavaFX (сам с ней работаю сейчас)
а для второго почитать что-то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994283/4420055)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2):

Благодарю. Я разобрался. Нужно было добавить всего несколько строк в main-класс (в начало файла, при объявлении переменных):

```
PrintStream out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.setOut(out);
```